# What does Fama-Macbeth regression model alpha (intercept) measure?

Tags: fama-french

I did a fama-macbeth regression and got alpha of over 2.3%. Dependent variable is monthly returns and independent variables are ln(size) and ln(book-to-market). I was just wondering what does the intercept measure?